# Using Ruby to increment a variable, which is then used by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a loop that, when it comes to a certain name will skip that record and display everything else:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
            <% if record.task.project.project_name == "SKIP"%>

            <% else %>
            Do some stuff like display...
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

If the loop doesnt come across any records with a project name "skip" then i need to hide something using jquery.
If the loop comes across 1 or more "skip"'s then i need to show something using jquery.
i have the javascript function ive written:

```
function show() {
    if (<%= @count %> > 1)
    {
        $(".toil").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".toil").hide();
    }
}
```

where `@count` is a variable in ruby intialized at 0. and incremented everytime the projectname is skip. i tried to do this with code soemthing like this:

```
 <% @records.each do |record| %>
                    <% if record.task.project.project_name == "SKIP"%>
                    <%= javascript_tag  do -%>
                        <% @count = @count + 1%>
                    <% end -%>
                    <% else %>
```

i know this doesnt work but id like to know how i would do this and if theres a better, more "Ruby-Way".

Comment: Why is the `@count` increment in a JavaScript tag? In any case, as long as the `show()` method is rendered after the looping, don't know why it wouldn't work, as long as you actually call `show()` somewhere.

Comment: No idea why the @count is in a javascript tag but thanks for realising. I want to call the function as soon as the records have been looped through... how would i do that?

Comment: By calling it, probably in a `$(function() { ... })` block at the end of the body. You could also so a `count` on this in the action and avoid rendering it altogether.

Comment: i already have called it inside scripting tags at the top of the page... and what did you mean at the end of your sentence?

Comment: You can't call it at the top of the page, you need to call it after your HTML has actually rendered to the browser. I meant that you could  get the count in the action, and based on that, decide in the template whether or not to render the HTML in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that I see:

1. Don't use jquery at all. Set a class on the element you want to show/hide based on @count directly in your view. Then use CSS to hide/show that element. If there's no reason to ever show the element if @count=0 then just don't render it at all.
2. Set a javascript variable in your view (not a ruby variable). Something like `<script>var count = <%= @count %>;</script>` and then use that in your js.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `@count` variable in Rails and generate a different *content* for the `show()` function, depending on the value of `@count`:

```
<%= javascript_tag do -%>
  function show() {
      <% if @count > 1 %>
          $(".toil").show();
      <% else %>
          $(".toil").hide();
      <% end %>
  }
<% end -%>
```

This way you do not need to 'transport' the `@count` variable to jQuery as you handle both situations on the server directly, keeping it nice and simple.

**Edit**: It seems that the `javascript_tag` in your example is used wrong, for more information/examples on the `javascript_tag` take a look at [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag).

Comment: @spartan2417, What did not work? You got an error? The wrong function content was generated? etc?

Comment: nope it just didnt work ... nothing happened... perhaps im putting this stuff in the wrong place? ive got the normal ruby code above and then the js code goes inside two script tags at the top of the page?

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully this solves your problem. If there is not JavaScript in the result, it is not due errors in the usage of your `@count` variable, but due to errors in the way you _generate_ the JavaScript!